# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

Im Trying To Render This Component

```
import styled from "styled-components"
import React from 'react'
import axios from "axios"
import { useState } from "react"
const Wrapper = styled.div`
display: flex;
background-color: gray;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
border-color: white;
font-size: 10px;
border-style:dashed;
color: black;


`


const CollectionImage = styled.img`
position: relative;
top: 7px;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
border-radius: 50%;

`
export default async function Collections({imgSrc,name,Price,symbol}) {
  const res = await axios.get(`https://api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2/collections/${symbol}/stats`)


  return (
   
  <Wrapper key={symbol}>
    
    <h3>Rank</h3>
    <CollectionImage src={imgSrc} />
 
    <h3>{name}</h3>

    
  </Wrapper>
  
  )
}
```

File I Try To Render The Component in :

```
  const [Data,setData] = useState([])
  const [solPrice,setsolPrice] = useState([])

  
  useEffect(async()=>{
    const res = await axios.get(('https://api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2/collections?offset=0&limit=50'))
    setData(res.data)

    axios.get("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr?symbol=SOLUSDC"
   
    ).then((res)=>setsolPrice(Math.round(res.data.lastPrice * 100)/100)).catch((err)=> console.log(err))



  })



   
  return (
   <Wrapper>
    <Statbox>Sol/USD<br/>${solPrice}</Statbox>
   <CollectionStats> 
   <h3>#</h3>
   <h3>name</h3>
   <h3>Floor Price</h3>
   <h3>Avg Price</h3>
   <h3>% Listed</h3>
   </CollectionStats>
   <CollectionsBox>
    { Data.map((collection)=> {
    
      const symbol = collection.symbol
      const name = collection.name
      const imgSrc = collection.image
     
   
   
     
      return (
        
        <Collections symbol={symbol} name={name} />
        
        )
    })
    
   
  
    }  
   
    </CollectionsBox>
   
  
    </Wrapper>
  )
}







export default Homer
```

Im trying to render the component in a mapping but im getting the error:
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.,
if i manually create the component in the main file (the file below) and theres no error but i  want to keep it in seperate files and it causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Collections` component should not be an async function. Besides, if you want to fetch data when a component renders, you should use an useEffect hook.
Your component would be something like this:

```js
export default function Collections({imgSrc,name,Price,symbol}) {

   const [result, setResult] = useState();

   // Here we are making an async call as soon as the component renders
   useEffect(() => {
       const asyncCall = async () => {
           const res = await axios.get(`https://api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2/collections/${symbol}/stats`)
           setResult(res);
       }
       asyncCall();
   }, []);

  // Here you can use "result" as you want, just remember that it's value is null until the request finishes.

  return (
   
  <Wrapper key={symbol}>
    
    <h3>Rank</h3>
    <CollectionImage src={imgSrc} />
 
    <h3>{name}</h3>

    
  </Wrapper>
  
  )
}
```